# Broken iPhone screen without siri

Tags: iphone, screen

My iPhone screen is completely broken and Siri is not operational.

I have not synced it to any computer before.

It switches on and I can see parts of the screen, so it is not entirely dead, but I cannot access it.

How do I retrieve my data?

Cannot use voice over and have not synced it before.

Is there software available to get my pin in without need to trust a keyboard or a Mac?

Comment: Did you have iCloud backup turned on? Without **ANY** backup the best youmay be able to do is take it to a repair shop and have it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about retrieving the data on your iPhone. This will be kind of hard if you can't access your screen.

First, you will need to connect your iPhone to your Windows or Mac computer with iTunes installed on it. You will see a prompt on your iPhone to allow the computer to access data on the iPhone. Click allow and enter your passcode. Then, you will need to take a Full Backup in the General options shown. Make sure that you encrypt the backup if you want Health and HomeKit data.

Once the backup is complete, it will be stored locally on your laptop.

If you get a new iOS device, then you can choose to transfer the data directly from the iPhone or you can restore from a backup.

You can try connecting a Bluetooth or USB keyboard to enter your Passcode if your screen will not work.

Good luck!